# Piping yes when running scripts from curl

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I need to run the following script when making a new docker image.

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://starship.rs/install.sh)"
```

The above script asks me to proceed and I have to answer with y/N.
How do I pipe 'y' into the above command, or is there a way to run without the confirmation?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, I would say just `$(yes | curl -fsSL https://starship.rs/install.sh)`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity thanks. But your solution outputs ``` -bash: #!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory ```

Comment: @rowboat seems I had to add both --yes and --force. Putting either one alone didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to not use piping, and instead add both force and yes options:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://starship.rs/install.sh)" -y -f
```